# event loop is closed - aiogram

Tags: python, бот, aiogram

Хочу просто отправить сообщение, код отрабатывает

```
async def send_cycle():
    await bot.send_message(id, 'test')
asyncio.run(send_cycle())
```

Но получаю ошибку ошибку из очень многих строк, одна из них

```
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Стоит ли этот код обвернуть в try, except или это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Решил эту проблему так:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(send_cycle())
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]